# Retrieve from drop down list and set label for Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display label when user choose one of the value in drop down list.
These are my coding.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Spend Amount </td>
        <td>
            <select name="amountSpend">
              <option value="Less">Less </option>
              <option value="More">More</option>
              <option value="By">range</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>​
```

For example, when user choose less, I want to display "less than 10" using label.
Thanks

Comment: I've tried the solution from the answer below and it work...before this I have some problem to display a label based on what user selected from the drop down list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `document.getElementsByName` to retrieve the select and handle the `onchange` event:

```
<label id="foo"></label>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Spend Amount </td>
        <td>
            <select name="amountSpend">
              <option value="Less">Less </option>
              <option value="More">More</option>
              <option value="By">range</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>  
</table>​

<script>
    document.getElementsByName('amountSpend')[0].onchange = function(e){
        document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = this.value + ' than 10';
    };
</script>
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/XkXrv/

Comment: yes,it works just like i want it...thank you...but what if I have more than one drop down list in my form?

Comment: then you need to give your `select` an `id` attribute and use `document.getElementById('yourselectid')` instead of `getElementsByName`